# Series of 8 Ntfs type 134 Warnings in System Event Logs

Tags: windows-8.1, backup, ntfs, vss

I have a Windows 8.1 workstation on which I have begun, as of a few days ago, to see in the System Event Log **a series of 8 type 134 Ntfs warning messages** logged 1 minute 43 seconds after the start of my regularly scheduled VSS-integrated system image backup, which is done via this command:

wbadmin start backup -allCritical -vssFull -quiet -backupTarget:G:\

The unwanted warnings (listed below) started after I re-attached and reformatted an external USB MyBook backup drive that had at a prior time been used for the target of the regular System Image backups, but which I replaced with a larger drive.  For a few weeks this drive sat idle on the desk.  I suspect that plugging it back in with the old snapshots still on there (before reformatting it) may have led to the system becoming confused about where its backup volume snapshot data structures reside.

**I don't know how to reset the volume snapshot subsystem to "start afresh"**, but I suspect doing so and laying down a full System Image backup would clear up this problem.  I haven't even rebooted the system since I started seeing the warnings; that might be all it needs.

However, before blindly just trying things I thought I would ask here.

Here is the sequence of System Log messages, which are repeated every night during the System Image backup:

---

```
Information  2:00:00 AM  Virtual Disk Service  3: "Service Started"

Information  2:01:21 AM  Ntfs (Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs)  98:  "Volume System Reserved (\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy198) is healthy.  No action is needed."

Information  2:01:42 AM  volsnap  33:  "The oldest shadow copy of volume C: was deleted to keep disk space usage for shadow copies of volume C: below the user defined limit."

Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."
Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."
Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."
Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."
Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."
Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."
Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."
Warning  2:01:43 AM  Ntfs (Ntfs)  134:  "The transaction resource manager on volume C - NoelC4 SSD encountered an error during recovery.  The resource manager will continue recovery."

Information  2:01:45 AM  Kernel-General  11:  "TxR init phase for hive \??\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy199\Windows\system32\config\SYSTEM (TM: {a4c8ef04-9431-11e8-83b0-1803734ec99c}, RM: {a4c8ef03-9431-11e8-83b0-1803734ec99c}) finished with result=0xC00000A2 (Internal code=7)."
Information  2:01:45 AM  Kernel-General  11:  "TxR init phase for hive \??\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy199\Windows\system32\config\DRIVERS (TM: {a4c8ef06-9431-11e8-83b0-1803734ec99c}, RM: {a4c8ef05-9431-11e8-83b0-1803734ec99c}) finished with result=0xC00000A2 (Internal code=7)."

Information  2:01:51 AM  Kernel-General  15:  "Hive \??\Volume{ef97e822-4c7d-11e3-824b-806e6f6e6963}\System Volume Information\SPP\SppCbsHiveStore\{cd42efe1-f6f1-427c-b004-033192c625a4}{0B5EFEA9-A4AA-4F43-8C5C-F4FD287CA71F} was reorganized with a starting size of 117997568 bytes and an ending size of 118042624 bytes."
Information  2:01:51 AM  Kernel-General  15:  "Hive \??\Volume{ef97e822-4c7d-11e3-824b-806e6f6e6963}\System Volume Information\SPP\SppCbsHiveStore\{cd42efe1-f6f1-427c-b004-033192c625a4}{18046E51-7164-4705-BF94-E607CE13F8E0} was reorganized with a starting size of 12558336 bytes and an ending size of 11460608 bytes."

Information  2:01:54 AM  Kernel-General  16:  "The access history in hive \??\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy199\Users\default\ntuser.dat was cleared updating 4 keys and creating 2 modified pages."

Information  3:05:00 AM  Virtual Disk Service  4:  "Service stopped."
```

---

The backups are succeeding, and there is no evidence of any actual problem with the disks, internal or external.  These basic checks pass:

C:\TEMP>chkdsk c:

```
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is C - NoelC4 SSD.

WARNING!  F parameter not specified.
Running CHKDSK in read-only mode.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  2686208 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  18601 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  3150960 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  232377 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  37457544 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

1874999295 KB total disk space.
1323380116 KB in 2275913 files.
    693288 KB in 232378 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   2928387 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 547997504 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 468749823 total allocation units on disk.
 136999376 allocation units available on disk.
```

C:\TEMP>sfc /verifyonly

```
Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

---

Thank you in advance for any insights you can share about how to clear the condition that leads to these warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that deleting several files then rebooting the OS has apparently reset the condition leading to the repeated warnings.

The files were hidden, in this folder, with extensions .regtrans-ms and .blf, and had dates months older than the date at which I started to see the warning messages.

```
C:\Windows\System32\SMI\Store\Machine
```

Notably the VSS-integrated backups remained incremental (there is still plenty of space on the real backup drive).

Further research had turned up vague instructions from a Microsoft person that had led me to look in that folder, and the dates on those files being months-old gave me the feeling that they may have been left behind by some prior operation that didn't complete.  I don't like "rebooting" as a solution to a persistent problem, and I really didn't expect it to work, but hey, I'll take a clean log.

Answer (score 1):

Just gonna necropost so this solution is recorded somewhere at least.

I followed all suggestions I could find online and still had multiple NTFS 134 errors logged regularly. Every time Windows tried to take a backup and invoked VSS.

Turns out this time when I cloned my disk onto a new drive, I included the System Volume Information folder.

Don't do that.

If you did, delete that folder in Safe Mode and it won't be constantly trying to rebuild things that don't need rebuilding, producing those errors.